# Evolução do “fracasso”: ainda significa ‘estrondo’? Alguma vez significou ‘estrondo’?

Tags: significado, etimologia

Ao ver a origem da palavra inglesa [*fracas* (Etymoline)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fracas) descobri que vem do italiano *fracasso*, que para grande espanto meu significa ‘gritaria, baque’. Neste [dizionario italiano](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=fracasso) vem ‘ruído violento e ensurdecedor’; a relação com o significado ‘malogro, insucesso’ em português compreende-se melhor de [*fracassare*](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=Fracassare), ‘quebrar com violência e estrondo, despedaçar’.

Fui ver *fracasso* nos dicionários de português ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/fracasso), [Periberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fracasso), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/fracasso), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=nXDM)), e não é que todos incluem o sentido ‘estrondo de coisa que cai ou se parte’?! Eu nunca suspeitei que a palavra pudesse ter este significado. O Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) confirma e diz que a palavra está atestada (não sei em que aceção) em 1707:

> **fracasso** *s.m.* (1707, JSSil 104) **1** som estrepitoso provocado pela queda ou destroço de algo; barulho; estrondo <*a casa desabou com um fracasso assustador*> **2** falta de êxito; malogro; derrota […] ETIM italiano *fracasso*

O sentido correspondente de *fracassar* vem também no dicionários ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/fracassar), [Periberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fracassar), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/fracassar), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=QdPZ)). O Houaiss atesta a palavra em 1656, novamente não sei em que sentido:

> **fracassar** (a1656 cf. Viriato) **1** *int* produzir fracasso, som estrepitoso <*as cataratas fracassavam no meio de nuvens de vapores*> **2** *t.d* fazer em pedaços, de forma ruidosa; despedaçar, destruir, arrasar <*a fúria do vendaval fracassou vários postes*> **3** *t.i.int.* não ter êxito; falhar, frustra-se, malograr-se […]ETIM italiano *fracassare*

**Ora, então o que eu quero saber é:**

- Qual é o sentido original de *fracasso* e *fracassar* em português? Quando é que aparecem os vários sentidos?
- *Fracasso* e *fracassar* ainda são usadas com os sentidos de ‘estrondo’ e ‘produzir estrondo’? Onde? Eu nunca ouvi. É usada no Brasil? Mas os dicionários não restringem esta aceção ao Brasil. Se já não é usado, quais são os exemplos mais recentes deste uso?

Comment: Tuda essa informação de fracasso estar relacionado a barulho tbm é inédita para mim. Nunca ví ninguém no Brasil utilizar. Mas vou tentar adicionar no meu vocabulário. :)

Comment: Também nunca tinha ouvido falar destes outros significados. Para mim, *fracasso* sempre foi o antônimo de *sucesso*, e nunca vi ela ser usada com outro sentido.

Comment: Eu também desconhecia esse uso, mas agora faz mais sentido a expressão "fracasso estrondoso" já que é um artifício repetir ideias semelhantes como uma forma de ênfase.

Comment: @Ailton, Tá bem visto, essa do "fracasso estrondoso". Eu ainda pensei que esse uso de *fracasso* como 'estrondo' pudesse ser especialmente brasileiro, por influência da imigração italiana. Mas pelos vistos é, atualmente, tão desconhecido aí no Brasil como aqui em Portugal.

Answer (score -2):

Usa-se Fracasso, no Brasil, para se referir à alguma coisa que ocorreu de forma errada.
Não é usada para se referir a "estrondo".

Comment: Por favor, procure responder toda a pergunta e não apenas parte dela. Também, procure encontrar referência para apoiar a tua resposta.

Comment: Na verdade, nem a parte da pergunta respondes devidamente. Alguns comentadores brasileiros acima já tinham dito que não conheciam *fracasso* como 'estrondo', o que é mais seguro do que dizer que no Brasil não é usado: ninguém conhece o vocabulário **todo** de um país; se vem nos dicionários, é possível que alguém use.